# `:has` functional selector behaves "differently" in Mozilla's Firefox Browser

Tags: html, css, firefox

As stated in the [MDN Web Docs regarding the `:has` functional selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has):

> The functional **`:has()`** CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) represents an element if any of the [relative selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selector_structure#relative_selector) that are passed as an argument match at least one element when anchored against this element. This pseudo-class presents a way of selecting a parent element or a previous sibling element with respect to a reference element by taking a [relative selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list#relative_selector_list) as an argument.

Based on my understanding, I can select a parent element concerning its child elements, given the condition that the selector used for the child element passes when anchored against this parent element. If the above is indeed true, then I should be able to select not only the parent element itself but also elements inside, after, and even before (although no example was provided for this) the parent element. This functionality is functional across all major current browsers (Google Chrome, Safari, Microsoft Edge, Opera) except Firefox.

For instance, here is an HTML and CSS code snippet that alters the background color and text color of a **`<button>`**, the background color and text color of a **`<label>`** within the **`<button>`**, and additionally appends width, height, and background color to the **`<div>`** succeeding the **`<button>`**, subject to the condition that a checkbox is checked (you can utilize either the label area or the checkbox itself to mark the checkbox as checked). As mentioned earlier, this functionality operates in all prominent contemporary browsers, apart from Mozilla Firefox. Is this an issue (a bug), or am I misconceiving the functionality of the `:has` selector?

```css
.container {
  height: 90vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
}

label {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

button:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #000;
}

button:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) label {
  background-color: #0f0;
  color: #fff;
}

button:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)~div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">
      BUTTON AREA
      <input id="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox-toggle">
        <div>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <span>LABEL AREA</span>
      </label>
    </button>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OT: nesting interactive elements is considered to be error, standards-wise. ("The element `input` must not appear as a descendant of the `button` element.")

Comment: I know, but for some functionality and using some aria attributes, then I don't think it should be a problem (though yes its bad practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page you link to:

[image: Browser compatibility chart]

`:has` support in Firefox is locked behind a feature flag because it is [not ready for production](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039).

Comment: More precisely, at this moment (2023-08-09, Firefox Beta ~ 117) that feature (when unflagged) works quite well **only for initial (static) content**. Anything interactive or "dynamic", like `:checked` or added/removed elements/attributes is buggy and is being just worked on; see the vast amount of "Invalidation" issues linked in the issue. (Also keep in mind this is the hugest most radical feature introduced into CSS so far, turning CSS inside-out and throwing most performance optimisation pretty much out of the window; so please be tolerant and patient while devs hunt down those bugs.)

Comment: How then would you select the `<div>` after the button using only css in the example I provided above?

Comment: Since a `button` isn't allowed to be an ancestor of a `label` or an `input` in the first place. I'd start by rewriting the HTML.

Comment: I know, but for some obscure css functionality (even though there may be better ways to achieve it using javascript), this is handy, as long as `role=presentation` is set on the `<label>`. Anyways I went with taking the `<input type=checkbox` ... />` out from the `button` and got a workaround it (to support major browsers, since most mobile browsers) also don't support `:has` according to caniuse.com